# Eigen : slow matrix vector product

Tags: eigen

I tried to run a very simple (sparse) matrix vector product (V0) on my laptop but it's very very slow ?... A naive implementation (V1) is very very much faster :

```
>> g++ -march=native -O3 -ftree-vectorize -funroll-loops -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -o matVecProdV0.exe matVecProdV0.cpp -I /path/to/eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb/local/include/eigen3 -mavx -fopenmp
>> g++ -march=native -O3 -ftree-vectorize -funroll-loops -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -o matVecProdV1.exe matVecProdV1.cpp

>>  ./matVecProdV0.exe 10000 100
    134536 ms
>>  ./matVecProdV1.exe 10000 100
    498 ms
```

What did I miss ?

My laptop has 4 procs (2 cores + hyperthreading). Using latest debian/testing with g++-7.2

```
>> cat /proc/cpuinfo
model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3687U CPU @ 2.10GHz
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

The code is:

```
>> more *.cpp
::::::::::::::
matVecProdV0.cpp
::::::::::::::
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib> // rand.
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define AVE 75000

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  if (argc != 3 || !argv) return 1;

  size_t n = 0; stringstream sn(argv[1]); sn >> n; if (n <= 0)          return 1;
  size_t p = 0; stringstream sp(argv[2]); sp >> p; if (p <= 0 || p > n) return 1;

  vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> ijAij;
  ijAij.reserve(n*p); // We have p values per col.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < p; j++) { // We have p values per col.
      ijAij.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double> (i, rand()%n, 1.)); // Get column in the range 0 to n-1.
    }
  }
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> mat(n, n);
  mat.reserve(n*p); // We have p values per col.
  mat.setFromTriplets(ijAij.begin(), ijAij.end());

  Eigen::VectorXd vec(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) vec(i) = 1.;

  Eigen::VectorXd res(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) res(i) = 0.;

  auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (size_t a = 0; a < AVE; a++) { // Average.
    res += mat*vec;
  }
  auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << " ms" << flush;

  return rc;
}
::::::::::::::
matVecProdV1.cpp
::::::::::::::
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib> // rand.

using namespace std;

#define AVE 75000

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  if (argc != 3 || !argv) return 1;

  size_t n = 0; stringstream sn(argv[1]); sn >> n; if (n <= 0)          return 1;
  size_t p = 0; stringstream sp(argv[2]); sp >> p; if (p <= 0 || p > n) return 1;

  int * pMatIr = new int[n+1]; pMatIr[0] = 0;
  int nnz = n*p; // Number of non null values: p values per col * n cols.
  int * pMatJc = new int[nnz];
  double * pMatVal = new double[nnz];
  size_t s = 0; // Scan.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pMatIr[i+1] = p; // We have p values per col.
    for (size_t j = 0; j < p; j++) {
      pMatJc[s] = rand()%n; // Get column in the range 0 to n-1.
      pMatVal[s] = 1.;
      s++;
    }
  }

  double * pVec = new double[n];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) pVec[i] = 1.;

  double * pRes = new double[n];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) pRes[i] = 0.;

  auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (size_t a = 0; a < AVE; a++) { // Average.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int startJc = pMatIr[i];
      size_t nbJc = pMatIr[i+1] - startJc;
      for (size_t j = 0; j < nbJc; j++) {
        pRes[i] += pMatVal[pMatJc[startJc+j]]*pVec[i];
      }
    }
  }
  auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end-start).count() << " ms" << flush;

  if (pMatIr)  {delete [] pMatIr;  pMatIr  = NULL;}
  if (pMatJc)  {delete [] pMatJc;  pMatJc  = NULL;}
  if (pMatVal) {delete [] pMatVal; pMatVal = NULL;}
  if (pVec)    {delete [] pVec;    pVec    = NULL;}
  if (pRes)    {delete [] pRes;    pRes    = NULL;}

  return rc;
}
```

Why is eigen slower than naive implementation ?

Franck

Comment: the naive implemenation seems wrong to me ( pMatIr[i+1] - startJc is zero for all i > 0, the pVec[i] in the inner loop should run on j ...  )

Comment: I already answered your question [there](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=141964).

Answer (score 2):

if I got your naive implementation correctly, the line `pMatIr[i+1] = p;` should be `pMatIr[i+1] = pMatIr[i] + p;` and `pVec[i]` in the inner loop should run on j. Once fixed, the eigen version actually runs faster on my system (>~40%).

note that the wrong code is fast because the for(j) loop performs almost no work ( `pMatIr[i+1] - startJc` is zero for all i>0 )...

Comment: You are right. Even with the fix, I still get a 2x down speed: matVecProdV0 runs in 136682 ms, matVecProdV1 runs in  64635 ms.

Comment: @fgh my advice is to fix your code and make sure it’s a fair comparison; use the forum ggael linked to for a broader discussion, do not post here until you’re sure your banchmark implementation is right ...

Comment: Now fixed, the bench is fair. The problem persists.